# java.lang.NullPointerException when launching Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse Juno and I get this error when I launch it on a certain workspace:

> An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException

Other workspaces that are checked out from the same SVN repository work well. Does anyone know why this might happen?

In the workspace log, I get the following exception:

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 4 0 2014-03-11 13:26:25.798
>   !MESSAGE Could not add repository index
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2014-03-11 13:26:37.470
>   !MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
>   !STACK 0
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui.history.SVNHistoryPage$2.getElements(SVNHistoryPage.java:631)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.getRawChildren(StructuredViewer.java:1010)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnViewer.getRawChildren(ColumnViewer.java:703)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.getRawChildren(AbstractTableViewer.java:1087)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.getFilteredChildren(StructuredViewer.java:917)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.getSortedChildren(StructuredViewer.java:1067)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.internalRefreshAll(AbstractTableViewer.java:701)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.internalRefresh(AbstractTableViewer.java:649)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.internalRefresh(AbstractTableViewer.java:636)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer$2.run(AbstractTableViewer.java:592)
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)

Comment: As the exception is thrown by Eclipse itself, that would indicate a bug in Eclipse or one of its plug-ins. Therefore all you can do is upgrade your Eclipse and its plug-ins.

Comment: Thanks. I'm updating it now, hopefully that will fix it.

Comment: As I usually suggest in these situations -> **create new empty workspace**. The issue usually resides in workspace `.metadata`.

Comment: Good hint! I made a backup and removed everything in my .metadata folder, then launched eclipse and re-imported all my projects. Works now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved: cleaned up my .metadata folder and re-imported projects in eclipse

Comment: A word of caution. This folder may contain some of your personal stuff, so move it to a temporary location instead of deleting. In my case, I lost my "Tasks List" which was stored in this folder.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the below steps works.

Right click on project > Select Run As > Run Configurations
Click on Select Other link next to Using VisualVM Launcher
Select Eclipse EDT launcher
Click ok

Answer (score 0):

If you are installed Hiber object in your eclipse and when you are creating a new project as like vaadin 8 project then showing that notification.
go to your eclipse market place search hiber object and expand the update/installed button then click uninstall and follow that instruction.

Answer (score 0):

For me I changed the system variable ***"java_home"*** to work with other software and that caused eclipse to show that error.
after changing it back to the original directory I was able to launch eclipse without any issues.

> ***so for those who don't want to take risk losing something I would recommend checking if the "java_home" variable didn't change or even got deleted.***

simply do the following:

- click on the window logo or search bar if it is enabled.
- write *"variable"*.
- you see *"Edit the system environment variables"*.
- click on *"system variables"* and if you don't see it check if you are in *"advanced"* tab.
- you can see two spaces "user variables" and "system variables" check if you can see ***"java_home"*** or ***"JAVA_HOME"***.
- if you don't then just add it and if you do see it check the value if it points to the right directory of your ***JDK***.