# NullPointerException in SetupUIPlugin.performStartup()

Tags: nullpointerexception

I developed a plug-in project using elipse and it was working fine as expected. I then exported this project as an archive file and imported it to a new workspace. On executing the project is the new workspace I get the below null-pointer exception. There have been few posts on such kind of errors in eclipse forums, but I could not find anything concrete. Please let me know if you have faced such an issue before.

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui 2 0 2017-04-10 22:11:10.525
>   !MESSAGE java.lang.NullPointerException
>   !STACK 0
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.SetupUIPlugin.performStartup(SetupUIPlugin.java:443)
>       at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.SetupUIPlugin.access$5(SetupUIPlugin.java:414)
>       at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.SetupUIPlugin$1$1.run(SetupUIPlugin.java:253)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)

Answer (score 0):

Two potential fixes reported here: [java.lang.NullPointerException when launching Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22326177/java-lang-nullpointerexception-when-launching-eclipse) would be to:

```
clean your .metadata folder and re-import the projects.
```

or

```
Right click on project > Select Run As > Run Configurations Click on Select Other link next to Using VisualVM Launcher Select Eclipse EDT launcher Click ok
```